# Viewing encrypted data with UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, security, uiwebview, uikit

i am making a file browser (for any file type openable by UIWebView - images, movies, audio, text, word...), which deals with encrypted files

the problem is, what aim doing right now, is to i decrypt the file i want to view and load it in a webview request

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];  
[self.webView loadRequest: request];
```

however the problem is that the file is extracted to disk, to be read...

**the problem is, that somebody could recover files deleted**

so i tried to use

```
[webView loadData:documentData MIMEType:mimeType textEncodingName:textEncoding baseURL:baseDocumentURL];
```

- the problem is, **i can't figure out the right textEncoding** (mostly utf-8 works for images and simple text), but **a bigger problem is, that i cannot play audio and video** possible due to the request is not loaded from file

is there a good solution for handling such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, however, you can handle the decryption of data on the fly using NSURLProtocol. In regards to viewing videos, there is a bunch of other protocols you'd need to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The NSData class that you are passing with `loadData` is a byte class that does not need encoding as it can handle various kinds of data. So if your decryption delivers not encoded data, you can pass `nil` to the `textEncoding` and it should work fine. Text encoding is only a data definition to store specific signs in (byte)data. If you get the data from an UTF-8 source, then the `textEncoding` makes it easier to handle this.